# New Ubuntu VM is not booting properly

Tags: macos, ubuntu, boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am attempting to create a Ubuntu VM using VirtualBox. I have successfully done this in the past.

I started by downloading the 64-bit desktop Ubuntu OS from the website. I then created a VM using all of VirtualBoxes defaults.

After that I started the VM and set the OS to the `.iso` file that I downloaded.

Everything started fine and I got the Ubuntu booting screen:

[image]

But after this the sceen went black I got this goofey sceen which has never happened before:

[image]

Sometimes the lines are acctually characters such as 'S' and '€'.

Something to note is that the CD-ROM and Duel Screen icons in the bottom stop flashing when the screen above appears:

[image]

I tried the 32-bit OS and re-booting the VM multiple times, but neither worked.

I am using OS X 10.11.6

Is their something that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a lack of video memory, bad settings in virtual box or just Ubuntu not refreshing itself right.

Try host key (eg Right Ctrl) +F1 to get to the shell) and then host key +F7. That should wake it up by forcing X to refresh itself.

Failing that, reboot and in the grub timer boot to text mode, and edit the startup to not start the GUI until you manually ask it.  Then you can log in and fiddle with X settings all you like.